# Missing Boost debug symbols on OS X

Tags: c++, boost, gdb, debug-symbols

I've never needed to include debug symbols before.  They may have been included by someone else on the project but not by me.

I am receiving a SIGTRAP exception breakpoint at a weird place and the GDB debugger log is displaying the following "can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory".  Most of the problems (if not all) appear to be Boost issues.

I am trying to debug a C++ application on a Mac OS X using CLion, which uses CMake.  Somebody mentioned that I may not have the debugger symbols installed.  I've been looking around at different questions and on the Internet.  However since this topic is new to me, the more I read the more confused I get.

Can someone help me figure out how to get the symbols I am missing?

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
python
>>>>>Function "__cxa_throw" not defined.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/cmdline.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/config_file.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/convert.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/options_description.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/parsers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/positional_options.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/split.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/utf8_codecvt_facet.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/value_semantic.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/variables_map.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/codecvt_error_category.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/operations.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/path.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/path_traits.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/portability.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/unique_path.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/utf8_codecvt_facet.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/future.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/pthread/once.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/pthread/thread.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/chrono/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/chrono.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/chrono/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/process_cpu_clocks.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/chrono/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/thread_clock.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/error_code.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/boost-VVHIjo/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/lockpool.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/corecrypto/corecrypto-233.1.2~26/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcorecrypto_static.a"
warning: `/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.1.2~2/Objects/coretls.build/coretls.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/system_coretls_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.1.2~2/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_ciphersuites.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.1.2~2/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_handshake.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.1.2~2/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_record.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.1.2~2/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_stream_parser.a"
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bdz.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bdz_ph.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bmz.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bmz8.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/brz.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/buffer_entry.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/buffer_manager.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/chd.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/chd_ph.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/chm.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/cmph.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/cmph_structs.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/compressed_rank.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/compressed_seq.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fch.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fch_buckets.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/graph.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/hash.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/jenkins_hash.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/linear_string_map.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/miller_rabin.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/select.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vqueue.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/BinaryCache/cmph/cmph-1~1091/Objects/cmph.build/cmph.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vstack.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

Breakpoint 1, idair::OPProperties::readProperties (this=0x7fff5fbffa00) at /Users/pdl/IDair/Development/ONEprint Projects/Oneprint/src/controllers/OPProperties.cpp:30
30      DeviceConfig deviceConfig("DeviceConfig.ini");

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
Single stepping until exit from function _ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4dataEv,
which has no line number information.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
Single stepping until exit from function _ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4dataEv,
which has no line number information.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007fff93019286 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::data() const () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007fff93019286 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::data() const () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007fff93019286 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::data() const () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007fff93019286 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::data() const () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007fff93019286 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::data() const () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

Comment: Try switching from the bundled GDB to one installed on the system.

Comment: I followed these instructions to install gdb:  http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/  

Still the same problem!  However, I did get a warning that the current version is GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9; supported version is 7.8.x  

Do you think I should try to install 7.8 ?

Comment: @YuriyGettya - Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942697/1735836

Comment: I'm on Centos machine. The suggestion was based on me not being able to debug pthreads with bundled GDB

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to CLion and CMake, they cannot cause GDB not finding the debug symbols. Where is your boost from? Self-compiled or from a packager like Homebrew or MacPorts?

Comment: @usr1234567 - I got a hint from Yuriy and switched from the bundled GDB and I had to update boost using Homebrew.  That made it work.  :-)

Comment: @YuriyGettya: Would you mind to make an answer from your comment? Then Lucy can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an answer from comments:

Try switching from the bundled GDB to one installed on the system. 
I'm on Centos machine. The suggestion was based on me not being able to debug pthreads with bundled GDB.