# gdb doesn't read the core dump on macOS

Tags: gdb, lldb, coredump

I've installed **gdb** formulae from Homebrew on OSX 10.10.5 to send a backtrace to developers of weechat (because **weechat** installed with Homebrew crashes every time I do `/exit`).

And got this problem when trying to read the core file:

```
gdb /usr/local/bin/weechat /cores/core.70087
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/weechat...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
"/cores/core.70087": no core file handler recognizes format
(gdb)
```

I've tried to do this with  with `lldb` instead of `gdb`:

```
$ lldb /usr/local/bin/weechat /cores/core.70087
(lldb) target create "/usr/local/bin/weechat"
Current executable set to '/usr/local/bin/weechat' (x86_64).
(lldb) settings set -- target.run-args  "/cores/core.70087"
(lldb) bt full
error: bt [<digit>|all]
(lldb) bt all
error: invalid process
(lldb) bt
error: invalid process
(lldb) thread backtrace
error: invalid process
(lldb)
```

Have no idea what am I doing, just trying to do whatever I can to address these crashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Homebrew GDB can't open core file on Yosemite 10.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680712/homebrew-gdb-cant-open-core-file-on-yosemite-10-10)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to launch lldb as

```
$ lldb --core "/cores/core.70087"
```